# Use subdirectories as classes in Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

If one would use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory('DIR')` for this file structure

```
main_directory/
...class_a/
......a_image_1.jpg
......a_image_2.jpg
...class_b/
......b_image_1.jpg
......b_image_2.jpg
```

How would one make a dataset from this file structure?

```
main_directory/
...class_a/
......subclass_1/
.........a_image_1.jpg
......subclass_2/
.........a_image_2.jpg
...class_b/
......subclass_1/
.........b_image_1.jpg
......subclass_2/
.........b_image_2.jpg
```

I want tensorflow to train on both the class and subclass for each image or maybe just train on the concatenation of each image's class and subclass names, that works too.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory('DIR')` uses the subfolder of directory given, as class for the model.
For your 2nd directory structure, it will only have two classes,
`class_a` and `class_b`

Look through this [tensorflow link to decoding images](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#decoding_image_data_and_resizing_it), it will help you.

In function parse image, you can decide what to use as label

```py
def parse_image(filename):
  parts = tf.strings.split(filename, os.sep)
  label = parts[-2]

  image = tf.io.read_file(filename)
  image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image)
  image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
  image = tf.image.resize(image, [128, 128])
  return image, label
```

Here it's only using the folder name which is containing image, in your case, if you run the same code, you will have only **two** class `subclass_1`, `subclass_2`. Because from class_b directory also, it will pick the same classes.
However, if you want to differentiate it, you can following changes while declaring label,
`label = parts[-3] + '_' + parts[-2]`
Now it will have classes as, `class_a_subclass_1`, `class_a_subclass_2`, `class_b_subclass_1`, `class_b_subclass_2`, total of **four** class.

Comment: is there any way to include the subdirectories too?

Comment: How many class you expect it to have? only subclass_1, subclass_2 from given file structure? or all subclass_a1, subclass_a2, subclass_b1, subclass_b2 etc?

Comment: a1, a2, b1, b2.